# WCF Service client - Switch between dev to production - Best Practice (deploy)

Tags: wcf, production-environment

I have a development machine with a WCF client, the development now is done
I want to switch to the production
so I got the WSDL link to the production server(same service, different link)

What do I need to change in the web config release in order to switch to the production?

Thanks

**Edit**
There is one more thing, when I import the dev WSDL I got this in my config, how do i create one for the production?

```
<identity>
   <certificate encodedValue="AwAAAAEAAAAUAAAAiMP2hRL597Js3Czdjo....." />
</identity>
```

Comment: What do you want to switch to production?? The actual service implementation, or the client??

Comment: @marc_s - the client, the server is hosted in another company. after i finished to development they gave me the production URL. thanks

Comment: In that case: just change the URL in the client's config file to where you connect - that's really all there is! This assumes of course that everything else (service contract, behaviors etc.) remains the same between dev and prod

Comment: You could run `svcutil` against your production URL and see what it puts in the resulting config file and copy that to your client's config

Comment: @marc_s - or can i open another project, import the production host and copy the generated value? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the difference between a prod WSDL and a DEV WSDL you need to use the svcutil.

Open a visual studio command prompt then run:

`svcutil http://prod/service.svc`

It will give you a location of "output.config". Open that up and look at the differences.

**Best practice for deploying** is to use the *Web.Config Transformations* that Microsoft has built into Visual Studio 2010. Detail here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx

The basic steps are:

1. Create web.debug.config, web.release.config
2. Make sure your build configuration settings say "release".
3. Edit the "web.release.config" with your changes using the replacement syntax found in the link above. You can replace any node in your original web.config.
4. Deploy the website using *one click publish* or create a *deployment package*.

Here is an example of a web.release.config that has replaces the endpoint's configuration area. Notice the *xdt:Transform="Replace"*, That replaces the whole *client* node.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <system.serviceModel>
        <client xdt:Transform="Replace">
            <endpoint address="http://prod/service.svc/binary" binding="customBinding"  behaviorConfiguration="LargeGraphBehavior"
                bindingConfiguration="BinaryHttpBinding" contract="CustomerService.ICustomer"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_ICustomer">
               <identity>
                   <certificate encodedValue="AwAAAAEAAAAUAAAAiMP2hRL597Js3Czdjo....." />
               </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```